# Different result phantomjs console or php

Tags: javascript, php, phantomjs

I want to have the html code of an external webpage using phantomjs. (I use phantom because i need to have some javascript executed on the external webpage before I analyze it)

I have the following script.js :

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  //prevent js errors from showing in page.content
  return;
};
page.open('http://www.google.com', function () {
    console.log(page.content); //page source
    phantom.exit();
});
```

It works well when executed in the the console. It gives me the whole webpage.

But when i call it from PHP, i have a different result. Here is my code which calls the script above

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 5);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 256);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 1024);

$response =  exec ('/Volumes/J/mamp/code/phantomjs script.js');
var_dump($response);
```

But the answer i have is cut and i just have :

```
string '</script></div><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="gstl_0 gssb_c" style="width: 510px; display: none; top: 243px; left: 5px; position: absolute;"><tbody><tr><td class="gssb_f"></td><td class="gssb_e" style="width: 100%;"></td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>' (length=271)
```

What am I missing / did not understand ?

thanks !

Comment: Have you read the documentation to exec? It's pretty clear: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: With the output parameter it works perfect ! thanks